# Aspectj (ajc) compiler gives error for method parameter pointcut

Tags: java, aspectj, pointcut

I'm using aspectj compile time weaving and I'm trying to apply advice for methods who has annotation applied on any of the parameter.

Method for who I want to apply advice

```
public void link(String departmentId, @ValidateMe(validatorClass = EmployeeValidator.class) Set<Employee> employees, SystemMessageContext messageContext) {
}
```

My Annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidateMe {
  Class<? extends Validator> validatorClass();
}
```

My advice

```
@Aspect
public class ValidationAdvice {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ValidationAdvice.class);

@Before("execution(public * *(.., @ValidateMe(*), ..))")
public void validateMe(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
}
```

my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.11</version>
<configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <proc>none</proc>
    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
    <aspectLibraries>
        <aspectLibrary>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </aspectLibrary>
    </aspectLibraries>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin>
```

It will give me compilation error `Error:(24, 0) ajc: Syntax error on token "execution(public * *(.., @ValidateMe(*), ..))", "name pattern" expected`

Answer (score 0):

My bad expression should be `@Before("execution(public * *(.., @ValidateMe (*), ..))")` (Space was missing after @ValidateMe).